# display mysql result outside the nodejs queries to be used later

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a nodejs mysql queries below which works for retrieving database queries as long as its contained within the nodejs queries. now i want to display the result outside the queries function so that i can use it later either by passing it to a variables but it displays error *`rows not define`*

```
var id=7;

var sql = 'SELECT count(*) as cntStatus,type FROM user WHERE id= ?'
connection.query(sql, [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Query result: ', rows);


const use-later_count = rows[0].cntStatus;
console.log(rows[0].cntStatus);
});

**// print the result outside query for later use not working says error rows not define**
console.log(use-later_count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log(use-later_count);` statement would be executed before the sql query is complete as `connection.query` is async.

You can call a function that needs this value inside the `connection.query` callback function

```
function functionThatNeedsRowsData(rows) {
  console.log(rows)
}

var sql = 'SELECT count(*) as cntStatus,type FROM user WHERE id= ?'
connection.query(sql, [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Query result: ', rows);

  functionThatNeedsRowsData(rows); // 

const use-later_count = rows[0].cntStatus;
console.log(rows[0].cntStatus);
});
```

Comment: Please can you illustrate further  on how to call this function and console log/print the value. Am new to nodejs. just learning

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the ask. `functionThatNeedsRowsData(rows);` is how you can call the function.

Comment: how do i get the values of  functionThatNeedsRowsData(rows).    i have tried writing function as in the code below but its not working    
function() {
  
  console.log(functionThatNeedsRowsData(rows));
}

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same issue.
To help somone else who might have the same problem, I resolved it using mysql2 and bluebird promise.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(
            {
                host: data.host,
                user: data.username,
                password: data.password,
                database: data.database,
                port: data.port,
                Promise: bluebird
            }
        );
    
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM entries');
    
        return rows;
```

Now I'm free to do whatever I would like with rows.